# Discretize or bin LAB colorspace in 2 dimensions

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, pandas

I have a lab colorspace

[image]

And I want to "bin" the colorspace in a grid of 10x10 squares.

So the first bin might be (-110,-110) to (-100,-100) then the next one might be (-100,-110) to (-90,-100) and so on. These bins could be bin 1 and bin 2

I have seen np.digitize() but it appears that you have to pass it 1-dimensional bins.

A rudimentary approach that I have tried is this:

```
for fn in filenames:
    image = color.rgb2lab(io.imread(fn))
    ab = image[:,:,1:]
    width,height,d = ab.shape
    reshaped_ab = np.reshape(ab,(width*height,d))
    print reshaped_ab.shape
    images.append(reshaped_ab)

all_abs = np.vstack(images)
all_abs = shuffle(all_abs,random_state=0)
sns

df = pd.DataFrame(all_abs[:3000],columns=["a","b"])
top_a,top_b = df.max()
bottom_a,bottom_b = df.min()
range_a = top_a-bottom_a
range_b = top_b-bottom_b
corner_a = bottom_a
corner_b = bottom_b

bins = []
for i in xrange(int(range_a/10)):
    for j in xrange(int(range_b/10)):
        bins.append([corner_a,corner_b,corner_a+10,corner_b+10])
        corner_b = bottom_b+10

    corner_a = corner_a+10
```

but the "bins" that results seem kinda sketchy. For one thing there are many empty bins as the color space does have values in a square arrangement and that code pretty much just boxes off from the max and min values. Additionally, the rounding might cause issues. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? I have heard of color histograms which count the values in each "bin". I don't need the values but the bins are I think what I am looking for here.

Ideally the bins would be an object that each have a label. So I could do bins.indices[0] and it would return the bounding box I gave it. Then also I could bin each observation, like if a new color was color = [15.342,-6.534], color.bin would return 15 or the 15th bin.

I realize this is a lot to ask for, but I think it must be a somewhat common need for people working with color spaces. So is there any python module or tool that can accomplish what I'm asking? How would you approach this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard numpy 2D-histogram function: [numpy.histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html#numpy.histogram2d):

```
import numpy as np
# a and b are arrays representing your color points
H, a_edges, b_edges = np.histogram2d(a, b, bins=10)
```

If you want to discard the empty bins, you'd have to do some work from here. But I don't see why you'd want that, because assigning future colors to existing nonempty bins will be much more work if they are not on a rectangular grid.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to repeat what Richard Zhang did in "Colorful Image Colorization" research: http://richzhang.github.io/colorization/

Here, author himself discuss this problem: https://github.com/richzhang/colorization/issues/23

Fortunately Zhang provides .npy file, that contains those quantized values. It is under: https://github.com/richzhang/colorization/blob/master/resources/pts_in_hull.npy

The only thing, you have to do now, is to load this file in your python script:

```
import numpy as np

pts_in_hull = np.load("pts_in_hull.npy")
```

It is numpy array of shape 313x2 containing values from your image.

I know this answer comes few years too late, but maybe it will help someone else.